# Object condition in multiple places/repeated code (DRY)

Tags: oop, web-applications

This is a fundamental application design question I’ve struggled with and flip-flopped on for years. We have a legacy webapp that doesn't really have a solid ORM, if that tidbit might influence your answer. To abstract my question let’s say we have a class Car, and a corresponding table in our database named car. Car has a few properties: color, weight, year, maxspeed    These properties directly correspond to columns in the db table.

In our application, we define the car as “classic old” if year is < 1960 and color = black. And in many places within our app knowing whether the car is "classic old" is extremely important (maybe we’re running a very illogical insurance agency which gives steep discounts and other perks to cars which are “classic old”).

All over our application, we do things like:

--list all classic old cars

--give the current user a discount if their car is classic old

--list all classic old cars with max speed > 100 miles per hour

--email the current user if their car is classic old and weights more than 1000 pounds

What is the best way to go about this? We have a legacy application that does this in some places:

```
getOldClassicCars()

select * where year < 1960 and color = black
```

and in other places:

```
cararray = getAllCars();

for each car in cararray
      if car.year < 1960 and car.color = black
               oldcararray = car.add()
```

The point being that this very important, fundamental piece of our application – is the car classic old – is “hardcoded” as `year < 1960 and color = black` in many places. Sometimes in SQL, sometimes in application code, etc. Obviously that is not good, but as we’ve refactored things I’m not sure we’re refactoring things the best way we can.

Comment: If you have a Car class, you could simply refactor the code to have the Car object contain a function `isClassicOld` which checks for that condition on that car object. Get your list of classic old cars by testing the list of all cars against that method.

Comment: @aidan yes we could. If we do that though, lets say we want to get all classic old cars which weigh more than 2000 lbs from the database. Do we do this: 1.) get all cars from the db which weigh more than 2000 lbs 2.) run every single one of those through isClassicOld   If so, the problem with this is greatly reduced speed, e.g. we have 60 million cars in our db that weigh more than 2000 lbs.

Comment: And if whomever downvoted could let me know why, that'd be great. I'm happy to change my question if need be, I don't know all the "rules" of stackoverflow. Downvoting without letting me know why is a waste of time.

Comment: This is an interesting question, although I think the original question could be better-worded. That might be why someone down voted. Another solution might be to create a static global constant such as `kClassicOldSelector = "select * where year < 1960 and color = black"` and use that throughout your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are stuck with the fundamental problem that

- you cant run your code on the database
- you want to be able to use the database's selection functionality on this criteria.
- you want the calculation of "classic old" to be defined in a single place (preferably code)

Lets enumerate the solutions

1: Put the calculation in a sproc and always use the sproc to retrieve cars.

The problem here is if you create a new car in code, its class status is undefined, so you haven't really solved the 'not in two places' problem.

2: Get the DB to run your calc via an assembly. for example you can get mssql to run functions from a .net assembly which you can also use in your code base to perform the same calculation.

Problem, its hard work. Plus essentially its still in two places, you have to keep the db up to date and ensure that the table is accessed correctly

3: Persist the calculated value on the DB, but perform the calc in the code

Problem, if the calculation changes the DB values will be incorrect and need updating.

3 seems to be the best option, as we will know when the calculation changes and be able to take some action to resolve the situation.

However, it might be best, given the fundamental nature of this calculation, to make that 'out of dateness' implicit in the way we structure the code.

Instead of simply persisting car.IsClassic we could add a CarStatusReport object with a datetime property. We then generate a CarStatusReport(2017) which evaluates all the cars at that point in time and saves that data in a separate table.

Our business logic is then no longer, "Is this car a classic?" but "What does the latest CarStatusReport say the status of this car is?"

You Business Logic will then reside in a single CarStatusReportGenerator service and any other logic accessing the IsClassic calculation, will be forced to acknowledge the ephemeral nature of the stored info.

Answer (score 0):

No optimal solution here. But, one good point will be to move all the business logic into the one place. If you can't (when you make methods or functions calculating some property, for example `isOld()`) then hide all those inconsistencies under the hood, so implementation users (conceptually) will never notice DRY violation from outside.